# Automatically numbering constants

Tags: cross-referencing, counters, automation

I would like to somehow use LaTeX to automatically number constants.

#### Some background

As a mathematician, in my daily work there are a lot of throw-away constants which are not extremely important in the discourse. So I will sometimes write inequalities like

```
\[ f(x) \leq c_1 g(x) \leq c_2 (g'(x) + h(x)^2 -3) \leq c_3 \int h(x)^2 \]
```

Since the constants themselves tend not to be important, to conserve alphabets, I call them all 'c' with a subscript. Now, it is a bit of a hassle to

1. keep track manually which numbers I've used up to a given point in the paper, especially if I am working on a large document
2. renumber the constants if I modified an argument. Say if I remove the middle inequality from the example above, for aesthetic purposes it'd much better to have `\[ f(x) \leq c_1 g(x) \leq c_2 \int h(x)^2 \]` instead of `c_3` in the last term. But then I'd have to go back through the document to renumber *all* the constants.

Now sometimes I can solve the problem using the convention that 'c' with no subscripts stands for a constant that can change from line to line. But often that is not feasible (suppose I do need to refer to individual of those constants and verify that they are indeed 'constant' enough for my purpose).

#### What I'd like

Now I am aware of the `newcounter` command to define a new counter. I even know how to use it to automatically increment the counter. So I can define a command that prints `c_\thecounter` and increments the counter so I get a running list of constants. So that solves half the problem.

The other half of the problem that I don't know how to deal with is how to *refer* to a constant defined previously. Naively using `label` and `ref`, of course, doesn't work. (I actually don't quite understand the inner workings of those two commands; so an explanation of why they don't work will also be helpful.)

As an illustration of what I'd like, it'd be great to have a pair of commands `\newconstant` and `\oldconstant` which can be used like this

```
% Create some new constants
\[ f(x) \leq \newconstant g(X) \leq \newconstant h(x) \]
% Create a new constant with a label
\[ m \geq \newconstant[cnst:m] m' \]
% Refer to an already defined constant
The constant $\oldconstant{cnst:m}$ defined above is actually 1.
```

Which will display something like

```
f(x) <= c_1 g(x) <= c_2 h(x)
m >= c_3 m'
The constant c_3 defined above is actually 1
```

What I know how to do is to define, say

```
\newcounter{cnstcnt}
\newcommand{\newconstant}{\ensuremath{c_\thecnstcnt}\addtocounter{cnstcnt}{1}}
```

and this will print the running list.

> Is there already a package that does this? If not is there a way to get the behaviour I described? (Especially the ability to refer back to a previous constant.)

Comment: I am not completely thrilled about accepting my own answer, but I feel that the package I linked to is a better solution then hacking my own commands.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using `\refstepcounter` instead of `\addtocounter{...}{1}` will make `\ref` work:

```
\newcounter{cnstcnt}
\newcommand{\newconstant}{%
\refstepcounter{cnstcnt}%
\ensuremath{c_\thecnstcnt}}
\newcommand{\oldconstant}[1]{\ensuremath{c_{\ref{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\newconstant\label{first}
\oldconstant{first}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah! I didn't know about that command. Thanks!

Comment: How can you distinguish the labels from other labels, lets say, labeling the current section?

Answer (score 15):

Since asking this question I've also discovered the `constants` package [on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/constants/). It does precisely what I want it for, and also saves me brain-cell from having to define my own commands and counters.

In particular one can declare new families of constants by

```
\newconstantfamily{name}{symbol=<symbol>}
```

(one can also tune how the subscripts are displayed etc.) And use this new family by

```
\C[name]
\Cl[name]{label}
\Cr{label}
```

(the first form gives the next constant in family `name`, the second also labels it with `label`, the third refers to whichever constant `label` points to. The default family has its symbol set to C. It also plays well with `hyperref` in the sense that no links are generated for the constants (the way I think it should be).

One note: the command by default is not aware of the mode you are in. So if you want to use mathmode symbols, it may be quicker to define a wrapper

```
\newconstantfamily{errorterms}{symbol=\mathfrak{e}}
\newcommand{\errorterm}{\ensuremath{\C[errorterms]}}
\newcommand{\errorterml}[1]{\ensuremath{\C[errorterms]{#1}}}
...
```

to make typing in textmode more pleasant.

Comment: (Re: no links are generated for the constants) ah, that's the thing I clearly missed

Comment: Well, in your answer I think if I just use \ref* instead of \ref it will be okay with hyperref. Though with showkeys it will still generate a bunch of new keys in the margin, which one might argue is actually preferable.

Comment: Be aware that constant package has bug affecting biblatex -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419686/8297

Comment: @ablmf: thanks for pointing that out! I'm changing the accepted answer as a result.