# Biber error with "constants" package

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, errors, packages, biber

I was trying to run `biber` (version 2.10; using Texmaker) when this error occurred:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.10 INFO - Logfile is 'provabib.blg' ERROR - provabib.bcf is malformed, last biblatex run probably failed. Deleted provabib.bbl INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

After a few attempts, I found out that the problem was the package `constants`, which I was using to automatically number the constants I define; removing it, everything works fine. I am definitely not an expert and I have no idea how to fix this, but I guess it's because the package `constants` is a bit outdated. Do you now any way to avoid this issue? Similar packages doing the same job are welcome too.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%%\usepackage{constants}        %%<--- this one produces the error
   %% \newconstantfamily{K}{symbol=K}       %% An example
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
   @book{rudin,
   author  = "Rudin, Walter",
   title   = "Real and Complex Analysis",
   year    = "1966",
   publisher = "McGraw-Hill"
 }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
   This is a citation: \cite{rudin}. \\
   %% This, instead, an example of use of the ``constants'' package:
   %% \[\Cl[K]{nameconstant}=e^\pi;\]
   %% now here's a new constant of the same family: $\C[K]$, while here I am referring to the first constant defined: $\Cr{nameconstant}$.
   \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can reproduce the error. Indeed, with the `constants` package the end of the bcf file is somehow missing. However, except for producing the error, the `constants` package is not actually used in your MWE. What exactly are you using it for?

Comment: I need to use several constants, and sometimes I have to refer to old ones; this package defines "families" of constants and automatically numbers them. Maybe I'll edit the question and insert an example of use of it.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you are looking for, but have you considered the `glossaries` package? Anyway, I don't know what in `constants` causes it to tamper with the bcf file. Let's see what others have to say. I'm not really acquainted with `constants` either, so perhaps someone else has also other alternative suggestions to make.

Comment: I've had a look at the `glossaries` package and it doesn't seem what I'm looking for; thank you, anyway.

Comment: constants.sty inserts `\@@end` at the end of the document and so hinders biblatex to write its file.

Comment: So there's no chance of using both `constants` and `biblatex`?

Comment: Imho one shouldn't use this constants.sty.  It probably breaks also other packages.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected so. There are probably more clever ways to do that task, I'll try on my own.

Comment: If I may, I suggest you take a second look at `glossaries`. It is quite a powerful package and does more than it looks at first glance.

Comment: Sure, I have to explore it a bit but I've seen it will also come in handy in other situations; in case I find something useful for this purpose, I'll write it here.

Comment: There are some example glossary documents at http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/#glossaries if you want an idea of what you can do with the glossaries package.

Comment: `constants.sty` destroys the `\AfterEndDocument` hook completely and disables all `\AtEndDocument` hooks that are issues after `constants.sty` is loaded. So quite some packages brake with `constants`, but many of those breakages can be fixed by loading `constants` later. Packages that use `\AfterEndDocument`, however, are broken beyond repair at least `biblatex` and `pythontex` are affected by this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It seems the OP has already found a solution that works for them, but maybe you also want to add an answer explaining what exactly is going wrong here. That would be really appreciated.

Comment: @moewe I added a short answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constants package inserts throught `\AtEndDocument` the commands `\deadcycles\z@\@@end` which end the compilation and so hinders biblatex to finish the `bcf`-file.

I don't know why the package does this -- it looks like a bad copy of the original code in the kernel -- but it means that the package can break other packages completly and so shouldn't be used.

Comment: Thank you very much. To repeat my comment in this slightly more prominent place: `\AfterEndDocument` is completely broken by `constants`. So all packages that rely on it won't work properly (I could only find `biblatex`, `minted` and`pythontex` that use this). `constants` also prevents execution of all `\AtEndDocument` issued after `constants` is loaded. That potentially affects many more packages, but could probably be remedied by changing the loading order in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the simple trick described in the first answer of the question [Automatically numbering constants](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/727/automatically-numbering-constants) does exactly what I want, and avoids that error caused by `constants`.

In my case, I needed several "epsilons", numbered increasingly, and the possibility to refer to old ones.

The following counter was added in the preamble (notice that `hyperref` is needed):

```
\usepackage{hyperref}    
\newcounter{epscnt}                     %% Defines the counter for epsilon
\newcommand{\neweps}{                   %% Used to introduce a new epsilon
    \refstepcounter{epscnt}             %%    with the right subscript
    \ensuremath{\epsilon_\theepscnt}
    }
\newcommand{\oldeps}[1]{\ensuremath{\epsilon_{\ref*{#1}}}}  %% Used to refer to old constants
```

And here's a (working) example of how it's used (needs probably some improvement, in case other constants are needed):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
     @book{rudin,
     author  = "Rudin, Walter",
     title   = "Real and Complex Analysis",
     year    = "1966",
     publisher = "McGraw-Hill"
     }
     \end{filecontents*}
 \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

 \newcounter{epscnt}            %% epsilon
 \newcommand{\neweps}{
    \refstepcounter{epscnt}
    \ensuremath{\epsilon_\theepscnt}
    }
 \newcommand{\oldeps}[1]{\ensuremath{\epsilon_{\ref*{#1}}}}

 \newcounter{uckcnt}            %% uppercase K
 \newcommand{\newuck}{
    \refstepcounter{uckcnt}
    \ensuremath{K_\theuckcnt}
    }
 \newcommand{\olduck}[1]{\ensuremath{K_{\ref*{#1}}}}


 \begin{document}
   Here are some numbered constants: $\neweps$, $\neweps$, $\neweps\label{tre}$; now a citation: \cite[99]{rudin}. Finally, new epsilons, old ones and other constants: $\neweps$, $\oldeps{tre}$, $\newuck\label{uno}$, $\newuck$, $\olduck{uno}$.
   \printbibliography
 \end{document}
```

[image: The output]

This looks good to me; if you have suggestions on how to improve it, I'll be glad to hear them.

Comment: Mattia, thank you for reporting back. However link only answers are not encouraged on the site. Would you be so kind as to expand on the answer and how you used that link to solve the problem here? (preferably with a MWE).

Comment: @gusbrs Sure, I added it, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It looks much nicer now. Thank you. (+1)