# How to number constants based on first use?

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir, counters, automation

Much like the author of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/727/27664), I would like to automatically number some constants in my document. A relatively easy way to do this is by creating a new counter, assigning a label to each constant on its first use, and then referencing to it later in the document (see [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728/27664) [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21305/27664)).

However, I would like to be able to use my constants *with the same command* throughout the document, and number them based on first usage, so that the following examples would work:

```
Here are some constants $\C{first}, \C{second}$.

Later, we reference $\C{first}$.
```

```
Actually, we forgot that $\C{important}$ should come first!
Here are some constants $\C{first}, \C{second}$.

Later, we reference $\C{first}$.
```

Respectively resulting in:

> Here are some constants $c_1, c_2$.
>
> Later, we reference $c_1$.

> Actually, we forgot that $c_1$ should come first!
> Here are some constants $c_2, c_3$.
>
> Later, we reference $c_2$.

If it helps, you can assume I will be using the `memoir` class.

Comment: I've bad news for you: `\C` is not really a good choice for your command name, because `\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}` would break the document.

Comment: @egreg Not to worry. I used `\C` in the question for conciseness, but in my document I used `\const`, which so far didn't result in any clashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

or with the first line uncommented

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcounter{Ccnt}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\C[1]{%
\@ifundefined{C-#1}%
  {\stepcounter{Ccnt}\expandafter\xdef\csname C-#1\endcsname{\arabic{Ccnt}}}%
  {}%
c_{\csname C-#1\endcsname}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

%Actually, we forgot that $\C{important}$ should come first!
Here are some constants $\C{first}, \C{second}$.

Later, we reference $\C{first}$.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.