# Label section from \thesection

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, labels, counters

How can I put a label on `\thesubsection` without using `\subsection`?

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcommand*{\subsectioncounter}{\stepcounter{subsection}\thesubsection}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection*{An un-numbered subsection}
\subsectioncounter\label{somesubsection}\quad Some text
\subsection*{Later in the document}
See \ref{somesubsection}. % I want this to print 1.1, not the section label.
\end{document}
```

Comment: use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`

Comment: @WillieWong wow, thanks, I've been searching for a solution for this for quite a while!  If you make this an answer I can make it the accepted answer :-)

Comment: Done; incidentally, many moons ago that ended up as an answer to [one of my questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728/119). However, since I didn't realize that was what I *should have* asked about, I doubt you would've been able to find it in the site search.

Comment: For an in-depth discussion, see [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5001)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter` for this.

The former does the same as the latter, *except* it also associate subsequent `\label` statements with the value of the counter being incremented.

Comment: +1. However, I would replace "sets the current `\ref` value to be the counter being incremented" with "associates the next `\label` statement with the value of the counter being incremented".

Comment: @Mico: I agree that is a better phrasing.